# TComPort : How To Check Response from an AT Command after Send SMS

Tags: delphi, sms, delphi-7, at-command

I'm using TComPort Component in Delphi to send Bulk SMS messages via GSM Modem. I just need to make sure that The Modem Reply "OK" before sending the next sms.
Here Is My Code :

```
  with cds_kontak do
    if not cds_kontak.Eof then
      begin
        sProgressBar1.Position := sProgressBar1.Position + 1;
        ComPort1.WriteStr('at+cmgs="' + cds_kontak.FieldValues['NO_SELULER'] + '"'+#13);
        ComPort1.WriteStr(mmo_sms.Text+#26);
        cds_kontak.Next;
      end
```

I would like to insert code to check the Modem Reply, if the Reply is "OK" then continue to next list.

Comment: The modem reply is asynchronous. You need to code the event handler `ComPortRxChar` that gets called when the modem replies. See the example code that comes with TComport.

Comment: i have already use code in ComPortRxChar :  
`ComPort1.ReadStr(Str, Count);`  
`mmo_ussd.Text := mmo_ussd.Text + Str;`  
what i want to achieve is to know when the modem Reply is OK

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding details here in the comments. While you are editing, also add other relevant code that you might have written.

Comment: All you have to do is `if mmo_ussd.Text = 'OK' then`

Comment: is there any other way to get the modem reply, example by using TComDataPacket in delphi